# Identify the difference in two samples using parts of a linear regression model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, interpretation

I've built myself a linear model which has a fairly good predictive rate.  I need to use this to explain the difference in customer satisfaction from one month to the other.  My intention is to have a waterfall chart showing the impact of environment factors (things that can't be controlled), process factors, and unknowns.
The sum of these factors builds the bridge from one time period from the other.

What I can't get my head around is how to calculate the difference by the different factors.  I'm thinking of it as a price volumne challenge that you might have for explaining change in performance, where you hold one thing the same but I run into challenges.

Imagine that I have 2 variables Age (Environment) and AHT (Process), mocked up data below.  How would you go about explaining how much of the change in Customer Satisfaction from average of 5.5 in time period 0, to 6 in time 1, is due to age and how much due to AHT.

```
 df<-data.frame(Time=rep(0:1,each=4),Age=rep(c(25,40,30,35),each=2),AHT=rep(c(1,2,1,2),each=2),
               CustSat=c(4,2,10,6,5,3,9,7))
df
testfit<-lm(CustSat~Age+AHT,data=df)
summary(testfit)
```

This model then calculates a Customer Satisfaction score for every line.  This then suggests to me that using mean values isn't appropriate.
This becomes a further challenge when what I actually need to calculate is NPS (net promotor score) which uses the proportion of the detractors (6 and unders) and the proportion of promotors (9 and 10s)
I was thinking could I just replace the values for Age in one time period to another, but these aren't the same customers and what happens if I then have a different number of customers in one period to the other.

Maybe this is simple, but I'd appreciate a bit of guidance on splitting out the intepreation of the model.

Thanks in advance for your time,
James

Comment: I don't understand why you don't include Time in your model. I could understand fitting a linear model without time to the first period, for example, and then test the null that the model doesn't change in the second period. But, given your research question, I can't understand why averaging over time.

Comment: Hi, testing whether two are different from each other is not the point I'm trying to get to. I'm going to assume the relationship is stable and then want to advise what has driven the change in the average custsat / NPS from period to period.

Comment: Interesting point on regression the time periods. So I know what the variables are for the general explanation model, then I build model with tinge as an interaction sunny variable for all variables to determine the change? Definitely possible

Comment: NPS is a calc taking the difference between proportion of promoters and detractors in the whole sample. My regression gives me a customer sat score for a group or for individuals. What I could then do is look at the change in the average and infer what that is in NPS terms, and based on what the model can't predict, that's my unknown. I think that's it

Comment: Back in the office and this worked perfectly. Post it as answer and I'll mark it as correct. Guess that gives you kudos f some form